# Hexagon Menu made in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm try to make a hexagon menu to look like this. but I have some trouble.

1. Keep it responsive.
2. Let them contain text.
3. The borders.

[image]

I have make this code, but it don't work so well when it come to contain text or borders.

The CSS

```
ol.even {
  position: relative;
  left: 5.45455rem;
}

ol.odd {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -4.5%;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 10.2rem;
  background: #1e2530;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 4.61538rem;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}

.hex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hex:hover {
  background: #ea7432;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The HTML

```
<ol class="odd">
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
</ol>  
<ol class="even">
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
</ol>
```

The result was this. but it can't contain text or borders
[image]

What to do so it work like the hexagon menu on the first image?

Answer (score 2):

Place the hexagon content in a new element and apply the following CSS place it properly:

#### HTML

```
<ol class="odd">
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hex-content">Welcome</div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex"></li>
  <li class="hex"></li>
  <li class="hex"></li>
</ol>
```

#### CSS

```
 .hex .hex-content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;

   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);

   color: white;
 }
```

For borders, you can use a solid thin outer shadow and a dark thick border to obtain this effect. [Here](http://csshexagon.com/) you can find a very good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but, you can check out my hexagon menu builder which I'm working on right now, you can customize the code to your will. [EasyHex](https://github.com/alalfakawma/easyHex)